# How to disable calling focus event on page leaving

Tags: jquery, focus

I've got this code:

```
$('#search_user').keyup(function() {
    alert('hello keyup');
}).focus(function() {
    alert('hello focus');
}).blur(function() {
    alert('hello blur');
});
```

`#search_user` is the `id` of an `input` field.

I focus input and next (without blur it) focus address bar in my browser and click enter. If I do that, I can see "alert focus". How can i disable it? I wanna have alert only when i focus my input, not when i refresh page with enter.

Browser: FF 16

Comment: Is there code which automatically puts the caret into the input box on load, for example `$("#search_user").focus();`

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about this.  Even checking `e.originalEvent` (which tells you if an event was fired by a click or by code) doesn't help.

Comment: Temporarily, I replaced the focus() function to click() and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [the `focusin` event](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/). `focus` fires when losing focus as well as gaining focus.

Comment: Check demo field here. http://api.jquery.com/focusin/ Try this case: Put caret in field and next put in address bar in your browser. What can you see when your press enter? "Focusin fire". The same situation is for .focus(). And this is what I don't want to have in described case, but how can i fix it?

Comment: Oh, I see. When you put the caret in the text box, you're placing focus there. When you press Enter on the address bar, focus returns to whatever field had focus before you changed it to the address bar. This occurs in Chrome as well, but not in IE 9. Doesn't happen if you press the reload button, nor if you press F5... Weird. I'm thinking maybe it doesn't actually do a refresh if the URL is not changed?... No, it does refresh, as it jumps to the top of the scree.

Comment: "Focusin fire" will be showing also when we put address to different page. So blocking refresh is not sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at maybe blocking it if `window.unload` fires, but `focus` doesn't bubble to `window`, only to `document` (at least, in Chrome), and `unload` only happens on `window`, and `focus` fires before `unload`. You might be able to do something in raw JavaScript, by attaching to the capture phase, but it would be kludgy at best. Sorry I couldn't help, and that I misunderstood the requirement.